# Getting Common Lisp Process ID on Linux

Tags: linux, common-lisp, pid

I am wondering if there is a way to get Linux's PID (Process ID) from Common Lisp's REPL. That is, I would like to know the ID of the SBCL or Allegro process from the REPL of the process itself.

Comment: This would have to use implementation-specific extensions. Standard CL has nothing like this.

Comment: You might try [osicat](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/osicat/): `(osicat-posix:getpid)`

Comment: On CCL: `(ccl::getpid)`.  To find on other implementations: `(apropos "pid")`.

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing in the Common Lisp specification that implements this. Process IDs are too implementation-dependent.

In SBCL, the [`SB-POSIX`](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#sb_002dposix) package provides Lisp interfaces to most POSIX system calls, so you would use `(sb-posix:getpid)`.

In Allegro CL, operating system interface functions are in the `EXCL.OSI` package, so you would use [`(excl.ose:getpid)`](https://franz.com/support/documentation/10.1/doc/os-interface.htm#getpid-op-bookmarkxx)

Answer (score 6):

There is a (basically) portable way to do this. CL  provides for reading files and one can observe that the pid of the current process is in `/proc/self/status` (also `/proc/self` is a symlink to the process’ pid but I don’t think there’s a portable read link).

Specifically `/proc/self/status` is a text file and contains a line that looks like:

```
Pid: 439
```

So you could parse the file to extract that.

But then once you have the pid there isn’t much you can do with it without system calls or `/proc` weirdness

Comment: What is actually `/proc/self/status` showing? The Pid of which program? I think `pidof sbcl` is the number of the program, isn't it?

Comment: In Linux there is a filesystem backed by the kernel (not on disk), called procfs. It contains one folder per running process and the file `self` is a symlink to the folder for the current process (each process sees this file differently)

Comment: hm ... but if I call from within sbcl using shell command - then it won't be necessarly sbcl's pid, isn't it?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. If you open the file in lisp then you can find the pid of your lisp process which opened the file. If you shell out to `cat /proc/self/status` then you will discover the pid that `cat` was assigned.

Comment: @coredump answered already this question in the discussion of my answer. Your hint with `/proc/self/status` is really the key to get the pid of the process. But if you would do `cat /proc/self/status`, it will give the pid of cat and not of sbcl.

Answer (score 4):

**Final Solution (to the biggest part by @Dan Robertson's and @coredump - thank you guys!)**

Actually @Dan Robertson gave the full answer - I realize in retrospect.
This answer is just the implementation of what he said. So give him the points!

```
(ql:quickload "CL-PPCRE") ;; for regex parsing

(defun get-this-pid ()
  "Return PID of this current lisp process."
  (with-open-file (in #P"/proc/self/status")
    (loop for line = (read-line in nil)
      while line
      when (ppcre:scan "^Pid" line)
        do (return (car
            (ppcre:all-matches-as-strings "\\d+" 
                              line))))))

;; to get current process id, call:
(get-this-pid) ;
;; returns for me at the moment using sbcl "12646"
;; this is correct as closing of all other sbcl processes
;; and doing "pidof sbcl" in the shell showed.
```

As @Don Robertson pointed out, the file `/proc/self/status` shows the program which opens it its "PID" number (every program sees it differently). Thank you Don, since this solves the problem of finding really the PID of the program (`pidof sbcl` in the shell would give several numbers if several lisp programs are running independently on the machine.
Calling external programs is obsolete, if we open this file then from within cl, like @coredump pointed out.

**PID numbers of other programs**

```
;; Thanks to @coredump - who suggested to use 
;; `ppcre:split :whitespace-char-class` for capturing arbitrary numbers
;; in the answer string - I added a test for integer-string-p to clean
;; non-numberic values after split.

(ql:quickload "CL-PPCRE")

(defun integer-string-p (string)
  "Does string constist only of '01234567890' characters?"
  (reduce (lambda (x y) (and x y))
      (mapcar (lambda (c) (member c (coerce "1234567890" 'list)))
          (coerce string 'list))))

(defun extract-integers-from-string (s)
  "Return integer-words of s."
  (let ((l (ppcre:split :whitespace-char-class s)))
    (remove-if-not #'integer-string-p l)))

(defun pid-numbers (program-name)
  "Return PID numbers of a program in current machine."
  (let ((pid-line (with-output-to-string (out)
            (external-program:run "pidof" (list program-name)
                      :output out))))
    (extract-integers-from-string pid-line)))

;; call it
(pid-numbers "sbcl")
(pid-numbers "firefox")

;; * (pid-numbers "sbcl")
;; ("16636" "12346")
;; * (pid-numbers "firefox") 
;; ("24931" "19388" "19122" "10800" "10745") ; yeah I have many open :D
```

Comment: You could use `(ppcre:split :whitespace-char-class output)` to handle an arbitrary number of pids.

Comment: Hey @coredump thank you! I was asking myself how one could handle arbirary number of pids! Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you run an external program, you are creating a new process! the pid you get is the one from grep. See: `(with-open-file (in #P"/proc/self/status") (loop for line = (read-line in nil) while line when (ppcre:scan "^Pid" line) do (print line)))`

Comment: Ah yes ... so opening/scanning the file from within cl is necessary - and then the multiple pid from `pidof sbcl` would be obsolete ... thank you @coredump and @Dan Robertson! I think I now got it - how one can scan it ...